# Run Macro that has two For and If statements

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro that will remove any rows that have a `#REF!` as well as remove the header. On top of all of that, I would also like for the macro to go through and apply this option for all worksheets except the first one.

When I try to run it acts as if it worked, but when I checked the specific worksheets where this applies nothing has happened.

```
Sub RemoveGamesOut()
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each ws In Worksheets
      If ws.Name <> "1962-63 Stats" Then ws.Range ("C6:C5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
  For i = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row To 5 Step -1
      If IsError(Cells(i + 1, "C")) = True Then Rows(i).Resize(2).Delete
Next i
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: use Full `IF` syntax, `IF.... THEN {ELSE} ... End If`. Use full sheet ranges like `ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row` and `ws.Cells(i + 1, "C")`

Comment: Although I see nothing wrong with single-line `If` statements (I never use them myself, but accept that other people prefer them for stylistic reasons), the suggestion by @cyboashu about qualifying your `Range` and `Cells` and `Rows` with the worksheet that they are referring to will almost certainly fix your problem.

Comment: Also, you should fix your indentation.  Having nested `For` loops that line up in the same column like that is hella hard to see what is going on at a glance.  You might want to try [Rubberduck's SmartIndenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) on it. Full disclosure, I'm a contributor to that project.

Comment: (@Comintern - Sorry, but I don't know how else to message you, but just wanted to say Thanks for your contribution to the SmartIndenter, I use it *all the time*!!!)

Comment: @BruceWayne - Thanks!  Best place to ping me is in the [RD chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking). ;-)

Comment: I tried @cyboashu's option and ran into another issue when trying to run this. I got an error Compile error: Invalid Use of property on the row containing the ws.Range statement.

Comment: Here is what I am currently using for my code                                      Sub RemoveGamesOut()
Dim ws As Worksheet
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each ws In Worksheets
      If ws.Name <> "1962-63 Stats" Then ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row
     Else: If (ws.Cells(i + 1, "C")) = True Then Rows(i).Resize(2).Delete
     End If
Next ws
End Sub

Comment: @MKTrain add `ws.` before `Rows.Count` to count the rows on the `ws` worksheet. Otherwise it just counts the active sheet's rows

Comment: {Sub RemoveGamesOut()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For i = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(3).Row To 5 Step -1
            If ws.Name <> "1962-63 Stats" Then
            Else: If (ws.Cells(i + 1, "C")) = True Then Rows(i).Resize(2).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub}

Comment: I tried to add the ws. before Rows.Count and it runs, but it does not delete any of the rows within the worksheets that I am working on. Any way to get around this so that the rows that meet these conditions actually delete within the worksheets?

Comment: You need to put `ws.` before any time you reference `Cells()`, `Rows`, `Columns()`, etc. otherwise it'll just run on the active sheet.